# How can I set the background of a linearLayout to be at half opacity but not it's children?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

Basically i want an activity with half transparent/black backgound.ie the parent activity gets dimmed when the new activity is launched.

I was able to get a fully transparent background but using the following in my manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.xxx.FullPhotoActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" ></activity>
```

But i need the background to be kind of dark but also transparent.

I have also tried adding alpha to my linearlauout but that applies it to the child elements as well.

Comment: set android:background="#66FFFFFF" as property for your LinearLayout ?

Comment: @blackbelt Won't that affect its children as well?

Comment: why should it  ? Have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to blackbelt's comment i managed to get it to work with a combination of the following

Linearlayout background color #EA000000

Activity declaration `<activity android:name="com.xxx.FullPhotoActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" ></activity>`